# Input not converted to string?

Tags: java

I'm just getting started with Java (via an edX class), and one of the assignments is to create a vacation planner program that gathers information from the user. When I run the code in terminal, it works, but the strings "name" and "place" are not displayed correctly. Instead, the lines after the string declarations are displayed as "Nice to meet you + name + where are you traveling to?". Am I missing something that would have the input assigned to "name" displayed in the sentence?

The code below is for 1 of 4 methods that will be in the program. Image of my output:

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class projectplanner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        partOne();
        partTwo();
        partThree();
        partFour();
       }

 public static void partOne() {
     [enter image description here][1]  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Welcome to Vacation Planner!");
       System.out.print("What is your name?" + "");
       String name = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + name + "where are you travelling to?");
       String place = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Great! " + place + " sounds like a great trip.");
}
```

Comment: what is your expected result? and where is your main method? please share the entire code

Comment: This snippet as it is should work for what you describe. Can you show the input and corresponding output for us to get a better idea of what's wrong?

Comment: The code is working for me other than the fact that you need a space before `"where are you"` so it isn't connected to the name.

Comment: can you share your output and be more specific about your query ?

Comment: Code works fine for me. Pay attention on System.out.print in 3rd line.

Comment: Are you sure the code you've pasted here is the one being run? That output is characteristic of not closing quotes (`"`) before `name`, and enclosing the whole thing.

Comment: @TheGamer007 ahhhh, I took a closer look at this and this was the main problem. ‍♀️Thank you everyone for your help!